# Update a Web Page as a Process Runs

Tags: c#, html, ajax

I have a page where a multitude of time consuming functions occur. What I would like to do is as each step of the process is completed, update the web page to let the user know what step has just been completed. Essentially the user submits a query, then the server queries a database, processes the data, draws an image and displays the results on the page. I want the web page to say what step the function is on. It would say, "Querying" then "Processing"... ect.

Pseudo:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e){

    //display that the process has begun
    List queryResults = Query()
    //display that the query is finished
    foreach(item in queryResults){
       ProcessItem(item)
       //display that item has been processed
       Render(item)
       //display item has been rendered
    }

}
```

I have looked into using Ajax to update the page without reloading it, but from my simple understanding (zero experience with Ajax) the client would be requesting a file from the server. Is Ajax the tool I need for this? And if so, does that mean that in the commented area I would send a ajax response to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web servers can't push unsolicited data to the client; they obey the request-response cycle.  The alternative is to use Message Queuing at a significant increase in complexity.

Polling from the client is not so bad; web servers are adept at handling many short requests, and a polling interval of 2 or 3 seconds should be fast enough.

Here is a polling method I like to use.  It asynchronously waits for the response to come back before polling again (requires jQuery):

```
function poll(url, task, progressBar, resultsCallback, 
        timeoutMillis, pollIntervalMillis) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: timeoutMillis,
        data: 'action=poll&task='+task,
        success: (function(response, status, xhr) {
            if ('progress' in response) {

                // update the UI with the progress
                progressBar.setValue(response.progress);
            }
            if ('status' in response) {
                if (response.status == 'pending') {

                    // task is not finished, continue polling
                    setTimeout((function() {
                        poll(url, task, progressBar, resultsCallback, 
                                timeoutMillis, pollIntervalMillis);
                    }), pollIntervalMillis);
                }
                else {

                    // task completed
                    if (response.status == 'cancelled') {
                        progressBar.setColor('red');
                        progressBar.setText("Task '"+task+"' was cancelled");
                    }
                    else {
                        progressBar.setColor('green');
                        progressBar.setText("Task '"+task+"' complete");
                    }

                    // GET the results
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'GET',
                        timeout: timeoutMillis,
                        data: 'action=results&task='+task,
                        success: (function(response, status, xhr) {
                            resultsCallback(response, status, xhr);
                        }),
                        error: error
                    });
                }
            }
        }),
        error: error
    });

    function error(xhr, status, err) {
        alert('Failure to communicate with server: ' + status + ', ' + err);
    }
}
```

And your server-side code should be responding to polls with something like this:

```
{"progress" : 42, "status" : "pending"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did it with AJAX, you'd need to have clientside javascript executing the ajax request on a frequency to find out if the state updated or not. The other option is using silverlight on the client, it's capable of having a more robust event driven conversation.

Both are viable and good options.

Here's your general getting started space for silverlight+wcf:
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services

Comment: Can you elaborate or direct me to a good source on this? I would rather not have the client constantly pinging the server to ask if a step is done. I'd rather have the server send a message to the client at the end of each step.

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request polling at a regular interval is the most common option or you could turn off buffering of the http response and stream the status updates back to the client all within a single http request.  If this is a long running operation you need to consider user experience and scalability carefully in the latter scenario.

Html 5 WebSockets will address this specific scenario also.  However, I'm not sure what state these are at within the current crop of Html 5 compliant browsers.

Comment: an open socket on the server also doesn't have guaranteed clientside timeout rules considering web browser and network/proxy/firewall variety