# Use Ajax to update progress of process running in codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, progress-bar

This is a followup on a question I asked earlier.

[Update a Web Page as a Process Runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849236/update-a-web-page-as-a-process-runs)

I want the webpage to display what stage the process is running using Ajax. After each step in the code behind, a file is overwritten with some text indicating what just happened. I want the webpage to periodically send a request for that file and display its contents using either setInterval or setTimeout. Once the button is pressed, the webpage starts its request cycle and the server begins its time consuming operation.

What I have now...

Script for periodic requests:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var d = setInterval("Check()", 3000);
    function Check() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            alert("get chrome");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "temp/test.txt", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    /*$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(Check());
    });*/
</script>
```

Currently Check() starts running as soon as the page loads. I would like it to only be called once the click event happens. If I define the Check() inside the click event, it doesn't recognize the setInterval and will only check if I click the button again. This isn't a huge problem as I think it will be ok to have the script running. It will just display a "not searching" string. Unfortunately as the file gets updated (and I checked that it was) the page does not display the contents as it gets the response. It just remains the same, then once the codebehind finishes, it resets to the default setting. Can anyone tell me why the page isn't updating?

edit: forgot to mention that the click event has an onclick assigned to the C# codebehind that does the long function. I don't know if I can have the javascript Ajax function running and the C# codebehind going too. The Ajax calls have async = true, but the script part isn't running parallel to codebehind right?

edit again: I changed the script to count upwards. I expected it to continue to count while the codebehind did its thing, but once you hit the button it stops. Once the codebehind finishes it restarts the count. Why doesn't the counting keep going? I expect it to restart once the codebehind is finished, but I thought it would keep counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval("Check()", 3000);` should be called on the button click event. Don't invoke `Click()` directly on the button click event, just invoke the `setInterval("Check()", 3000);` and it will invoke `Click()` for you.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more? How do I invoke setInterval() to happen when the button is clicked without invoking the click event?

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#uploadbutton").click(function () {
                setInterval("Check()", 1000);
            });
        });

That's one way I tried it, but it invokes the button click event. Nothing happens this way.

Comment: If I change the Check() to just count upwards it works. As the codebehind runs the page counts. Any ideas why it doesn't work when the Ajax functions are called?

Comment: The javascript in your comment looks fine, it run the anonymous function when the button is clicked which should start the interval for your Click() function. Is there a reason you aren't using the ajax library that's part of jQuery? It will handle ajax call no matter what browser they are using. Also, instead of setting a timer (since it may take a while for the ajax response to come back), set your code up such that it waits for the ajax call to return before making another ajax call (they could start overlapping with the way you have it).