# Java - understanding servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on a homework project that should implement a board game between 2 clients over an HttpServlet. I have couple of questions:

1) I read that HttpServlets must be stateless, however, for the sake of the game, I have to keep a lot of state(whose turn it is, the state of the board, etc). Do I have to keep this in the clients? Does the HttpServlet indeed have to be stateless, i.e. have no fields that track state?

2) I know that the clients will talk to the servlet via the doGet/doPost methods, but how can the servlet talk to the clients(for example, if player 1 just made a move and sent it to the servlet, the servlet has to tell client 2 what the move was).

Thank you

Also, if you can point me to a useful, simple example of a similar code online, I would be very grateful

Comment: 2)  See an example of polling [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849236/update-a-web-page-as-a-process-runs/6849768#6849768)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. HTTP protocol is stateless and hence the HttpServlet. You can maintain session state on server side using servlet api. Read [Session Management tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html).
2. There are several techniques like H[TML auto-refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), technologies like [Comet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/) and [HTML 5's WebSocket](http://ajeeshwrites.blogspot.com/2011/02/peek-at-websockets.html)

Comment: Why does your 1) contradict with Dave Newton's? Also, the link in 1) doesn't work.

Comment: @Trup 1) We both are talking the same thing. HTTP is stateless as I've mentioned but Servlet provides API for you to manage state though. The link is working for me but I've changed to another link for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. So, you are saying the Servlet class cannot simply save state in a field, just like any other class? What is the next simplest thing to do then?

Comment: @Trup Servlets can save state in a field, but the *access* to that field must be synchronized--typical multi-threading issues. If the server must maintain the state of the world for multiple players there will be *something* somewhere that has shared state that must be thread-safe. It doesn't *have* to be in a servlet, it could be, say, in application scope, a static (ew, but meh, it's gotta go somewhere), etc.

Comment: @Trup - Only 1 object of the servlet is created to serve all client requests. This means that storing state in the servlet is not thread-safe and not recommended. Moreover, servlet has inbuilt api to ENABLE state mgmt over a stateless protocol so it is better to leverage that than building your own.

Comment: Note that this is homework assignment however, so let's make the following 2 assumptions: 1) the players will connect at different times, so no sync issues there  2) they will only enter moves when requested by the servlet, so no sync issues there. Is it then safe to keep state in the servlet in a normal, non-fancy way?

Comment: @Pangea But the nature of a two-player game means there will be shared state *somewhere*, and the server must ensure integrity, no? Sessions alone aren't enough; something has to aggregate player data.

Comment: @Trup Safe-ish. (Read: no, but for *your* purposes, it may be adequate, as long as nobody does anything remotely different than precisely what you expect.)

Comment: Ok. How about question 2), can you please show me a simple example of the servlet talking to the clients? Thanks a lot, both of you have been very helpful!

Comment: @DaveNewton Yep for aggregation the state can be managed in the servlet or at application scope.

Answer (score 2):

Servlets need to be able to handle multiple requests--they don't need to be stateless, but they must *manage* that state to avoid the typical multi-threading issues. Obviously if you have two users that need to access the same world you need a mechanism for that. Presumably the server will help keep track of game state, if for no other reason than to avoid cheating or malicious clients.

There are a variety of options; clients can poll for move updates, you can use long-polling, etc.

Comment: What do you mean about polling? Is this about my 2nd question? Any examples how this is done?

Comment: @Trup There's short-polling (page refresh, timer/ajax, etc) and long-polling (comet etc) and finding examples should be pretty easy. Not too familiar with long-polling myself, so not comfortable pointing at anything specific.

Answer (score 1):

The others have already covered #1.

I'll just make a recommendation for #2.  Another option would be to take a quick look at AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML).  You can fire "behind-the-scenes" HTTP requests and adjust the page without requiring the user to refresh the page.  The client can load the HTML page which can have javascript that checks with the server every few seconds for updates and refreshes their board.

[Here's a small example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp).  Also, if you want to not worry about browser-specific javascript, you can play around with jQuery.  It has pretty user-friendly api's for firing ajax requests and it handles the browser-specific stuff.

EDIT

Okay, for #1 - Your servlet is going to be used to service all requests, potentially in parallel.  You can't put your game board directly in the servlet b/c then you could have 20 people trying to edit the same game.

```
public class GameServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private GameBoard board; // everyone would share the same board!
```

You have a couple options, you can store boards in some collection that you access by user.  You may also want to take a look at HttpSession.  HttpSession is a section of server-side memory that the servlet will keep track of for you that you can access across requests.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

  HttpSession session = req.getSession();
  session.setAttribute("board", new GameBoard());  // this way each user will have their own game board

  // and you can retrieve it in another HTTP request
  GameBoard board = session.getAttribute("board");
}
```

Using HttpSession may be a little trickier for you since a board update will actually have to update two user's boards.  You might favor just a collection member on the servlet that is indexed by user(s).  Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Can I get an example on #1? I still don't quite understand what am I supposed to do / what I can do

Answer (score 0):

HTTP as a protocol is stateless (as people have mentioned).  However, a small part http is passing "Cookies" back and forth between the server and client.  These cookies are a separate RFC (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) interperated by the HTTP client (ie. browser).  In terms of HTTP, cookies are just another header field, but they have special meaning to the browser.

One use of these cookies for a servlet based program to pass a session id back to the client browser.  When the client sends a subsequent request, that same cookie is automatically sent back to the server which issued it.  The server recognizes that and that identifiers the user session.  This is mostly transparent to the programmer.

Typically, tomcat (or some other container) handles this for you, and all you have to do is ask the servlet request for the session:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    // the parameter determines if session can be created if one does not exist for the client
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true); 

    session.setAttribute("attName", attValue);
}
```

You can use the session to store/retrieve attributes.  As for common game state, that should most likely bet stored elsewhere (some kind of game manager object), but you could store the current game id for the user in their session, which would allow the servlet to find the appropriate game for the user.  When a user makes a move, game state is updated via an http request which indicates this.  Both users would have to periodically make http requests to ask for the current state of the game, recent moves, etc....